# How to get value of first column when selecting a row in datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I want to store on a variable the value of the first column of a row whenever I click on a cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
private void MyDataGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var val = MyDataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

Hope this help you.